# stored procedure with a default value

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have two tables: one that is called `City` (City_id,Name, Latitude, Longitude) and the other is `Measures` (City_id, Measure_Date, Temperature, Humidity, WindSpeed, AirPressure).

`City_id` is the primary key in `City` and foreign key in `Measures`. `City_id` and `Measure_date` are primary key too.

I am trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 that allows me to calculate the averages of the all four measurements I have in the database for a specific city. And if the city has no records in `Measures`, I want the default value to be null.

How should I make it set the default value null for those cities? Thank you :)

Here is the code that I did:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[low_temp]
     @temp real
AS
begin
    select 
        avg(m.temperature), avg(m.humidity), 
        avg(m.windspeed), avg(m.airpressure)
    from 
        city c, measures m 
    where 
        m.city_id = @temp
end
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use left join:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[low_temp]
     @temp real
AS
begin
    select avg(m.temperature), 
           avg(m.humidity), 
           avg(m.windspeed), 
           avg(m.airpressure)
    from city c
    left join measures m ON(c.city_id = m.city_id)
    where 
        c.city_id = @temp
end
```

Comment: Glad to help. :-) However if an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.